# C# Web API : generic controller

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api, controller

Is it possible to design a base controller structure using composition instead of inheritance?

Basically, every model in my application has its own defined service where all actions for each model are defined:

```
public interface IPersonService : 
    IReadRepository<PersonFilterRequest, PersonReadResponse, Person>,
    IInsertRepository<PersonInsertRequest, PersonInsertResponse, Person>,
    IUpdateRepository<PersonUpdateRequest, PersonUpdateResponse, Person>,
    IDeleteRepository<PersonDeleteRequest, PersonDeleteResponse, Person>
{    
    // ...
}

public class PersonService : IPersonService
{
    public IReadAction<PersonFilterRequest, PersonReadResponse, Person> Reader { get; private set; }
    public IInsertAction<PersonInsertRequest, PersonInsertResponse, Person> Inserter { get; private set; }
    public IUpdateAction<PersonUpdateRequest, PersonUpdateResponse, Person> Updater { get; private set; }
    public IDeleteAction<PersonDeleteRequest, PersonDeleteResponse, Person> Deleter { get; private set; }
}
```

What I would like to do, is create base controller class for each action (ie. `ReadController`, `InsertController`, `UpdateController`, `DeleteController`), and then use selected controllers (depending on allowed actions on each db model) somehow like:

```
[ApiController]
public class PersonController
{
    public ReadController<PersonFilterRequest, PersonReadResponse, Person, PersonService> Read { get; private set; }
    public InsertController<PersonInsertRequest, PersonInsertResponse, Person, PersonService> Insert { get; private set; }
    public UpdateController<PersonUpdateRequest, PersonUpdateResponse, Person, PersonService> Update { get; private set; }
    public DeleteController<PersonDeleteRequest, PersonDeleteResponse, Person, PersonService> Delete { get; private set; }
}
```

And then, when user triggers an action, the appropriate controller (and its method) would be called (ie. if insert is triggered, appropriate method from `PersonController.Insert` property should be called)

Is something like this possible?

Comment: First of all I don't think what you want to achive is possible. But secondly, I think you should actually think about why you want to do this like this? Don't you think this make your code much more complicated?

Comment: It probably would be a bit complicated to set up (if its even possible), but since I have lots of models, of which many have different sets of possible actions (ie. only read, read/export, read/insert, read/insert/delete, read/insert/update, read/insert/export, read/insert/update/detele, ...), I think it would be worth it. Also, in that way I would be able to follow DRY principle pretty "elegantly"

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with **pawelfelcyn**'s comment, he is right. While your idea about generic controllers and composition is interesting and should be innovative, it's quite unconventional and could potentially complicate the routing in your ASP.NET Core Web API. The framework's routing system would have difficulty determining which controller to use for each request as it is designed to match routes to methods in a controller, not to properties of a controller.

That being said, you can take a somewhat similar approach, but not exactly as you've described it. Let me propose an alternative design.

You can create individual controller base classes for each action type, and then each specific controller can inherit from multiple base controllers using C# interface default methods (introduced in C# 8.0) as multiple inheritance is not supported directly in C#. Check this for example:

```
public interface IReadController<TFilterRequest, TReadResponse, TEntity, TService> where TService : IReadRepository<TFilterRequest, TReadResponse, TEntity>
{
    TService Service { get; }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<TReadResponse>> Get([FromQuery] TFilterRequest filter)
    {
        return Ok(Service.Get(filter));
    }
}

public interface IInsertController<TInsertRequest, TInsertResponse, TEntity, TService> where TService : IInsertRepository<TInsertRequest, TInsertResponse, TEntity>
{
    TService Service { get; }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<TInsertResponse> Post([FromBody] TInsertRequest entity)
    {
        var result = Service.Insert(entity);
        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new { id = result.Id }, result);
    }
}

// Repeat similar structure for IUpdateController and IDeleteController
```

Then, you can have a specific controller like:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class PersonController : Controller, IReadController<PersonFilterRequest, PersonReadResponse, Person, IPersonService>, IInsertController<PersonInsertRequest, PersonInsertResponse, Person, IPersonService> /* Add more interfaces as per your requirement */
{
    private readonly IPersonService _personService;

    public PersonController(IPersonService personService)
    {
        _personService = personService;
    }

    IPersonService IReadController<PersonFilterRequest, PersonReadResponse, Person, IPersonService>.Service => _personService;
    IPersonService IInsertController<PersonInsertRequest, PersonInsertResponse, Person, IPersonService>.Service => _personService;

    // Implement Service property for other interfaces as per your requirement
}
```

This approach enables you to create controllers with only the methods you want, while reusing the code via interface default methods.

As always, the right design depends on the complexity of your project and the specific requirements. Remember that the goal is not only to reduce code duplication, but also to make the code maintainable and understandable.Cheers!